# Dual boot - Kubuntu and Windows 8 - how to?

Tags: linux, partition, windows, dual-boot, kubuntu

I recently installed Windows 8 on my computer.

These are the specs:

- Fx-8150 CPU
- 8 GB RAM
- ATI HD7870
- 120 GB SSD
- 2 TB HDD
- Mainboard: Gigabyte GA-970A-UD3 (rev 1.1) (only bios but EFI mode possible for starting from CD)

I already tried in the past to install a linux distro after installing Windows 8. But during the installation a "critical error" occurred (without further details) and the installation of linux was not "clean". I couldn't install a lot of packages and I found out that there was no boot loader. When restarting it only loaded Windows 8 directly. I tried to reconfigure the partitions in linux but I kind of destroyed the boot partition and wasn't able to boot anything. I couldn't even repair the Windows installation and had to re-install Windows.

I need help in finding the correct way of using the partitions.

*Windows is installed on C: while D: contains only data*

[image: Partitions]

How do I pre-configure my partitions so that I can install and dual-boot Kubuntu? I'd prefer to install it on my SSD (having like 30 GB) but I would be fine if it's only possible to install it on the HDD.

I will be using Kubuntu 12.04 LTS (Installation DVD for 64bit)

- What do I need to do in order to have the correct bootloader (I presume it's grub?)
- How do I have to prepare my partitions for a correct linux installation?

---

**Update:**
When I try to install Kubuntu from a bootable USB-stick I don't see my partitions. There is sda with 120GB free space and sdb with 2TB of free space... How can I make the partitions I configured in Windows be visible in Linux?

[image]

---

**Update 2:**
It seems my whole GPT was corrupt. So I re-installed Windows 8, wiped out all partitions and drives and now have a clean Windows 8 installation looking like this:

[image]

Any advice on how to prepare the partitions for a dual-boot Kubuntu installation?

---

**Update 3:**
Here is what I've done so far:

- Shrinking C by 30 GB for my linux installation
- Leave the 30 GB unallocated
- boot from Kubuntu 12.04 USB stick
- Go through the installation procedure
- In the free space creating the following

  - Created /sda5 as ext2 with 250 mb and mount point /boot
  - Created /sda6 as swap with 4096 mb
  - Created /sda7 as ext4 file system with about 25 gb and mount point /
  - After warning from the program I did the following:

    - Created /sda8 as dos boot part with 1 mb (the program recommended it)
- as boot loader location I choose /dev/sda5

The installation starts without warnings but when it's almost done it says "grub coul not be installed in /dev/sda5".

I followed a tutorial step-by-step but still got the same message.

Any advice on that?

Comment: Windows usually hates being installed second. I've never cared enough about Windows to try to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can install windows 8,then install ubuntu.Ubuntu will auto recognize the windows 8.After ubuntu has been installed.The grub will has multipe boot options.The default is ubuntu,the other is windows 8.
    If you install ubuntu before windows 8,you can use ubuntu live-cd to boot system,and reinstall grub.This will regenerate the correct grub.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install GRUB to /dev/sda5 (which in standard notation is a reference to the 5th partition of the first disk) because that's not a bootable partition.  The OS is only going to check the first partition for a bootable partition, if you want to use it with Windows, I believe you need to install GRUB into it's own boot partition (if I were going to do what you're doing, I would have Windows  on disk A, then give Linux the first 30GB on disk B, and then give Windows the rest on disk B, the reason being that now you'll be able to choose which OS you boot into through the mobo screen, boot to disk A for Windows and disk B for Linux).  I'm sure there's a way to install them side by side, but I haven't done it in so long I kind of forget.  You may be able to just install GRUB into the Windows boot partition, just don't make a /boot partition and when it asks, select the first partition of disk A.  I would wait for someone else to verify that before you do it though, because I'm not 100% sure and I'd hate for you to mess up your Windows again.

Answer (score 0):

Hav u disabled secure boot from windows 8?

While booting ubuntu from live usb, try doing a sudo os-prober to list installed operating systems. If it shows windows 8, you are safe, else there is problem in UEFI bios, follow https://askubuntu.com/questions/435160/cant-boot-windows-7-after-installing-ubuntu/435364#435364

Install the bootloader in /dev/sda and ubuntu in /dev/sda5.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a dual boot with xp and mint where XP is on my first hdd and mint on my second. I've created a separate boot partition for mint on my second hdd (which automatically recognized the xp installation). the boot partition I've created is the *first* partition on my second hdd. After finishing the mint install (XP was installed first) I rebooted, went into the bios and changed boot priority for my hdd's: first my second hdd is checked, after that, my first hdd is checked.

Works like a Charm!

Ive just a guide for this, hope this will help also with installing win 8 and kubuntu together (don't have experience with win8 though):

[dual boot partitioning guide](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/07/23/dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7-on-a-computer-with-2-hard-drives/2/)